# Why does Thibadeaux let Mac and Gin go through with the heists?

Tags: plot-explanation, entrapment

In the film *Entrapment (1999)*, why would Thibadeaux, being an FBI agent, allow Gin and Mac to pull off the heists at all?

In other words, what was the point of letting them steal the mask and the 8 billion dollars? Why not just wait for Mac to bring her back to his place and arrest her there?